# list comprehension joining every two elements together in a list

Tags: python

How would I convert lst1 to lst2 by joining element 1 to element 2 and so on?

```
lst1=[' ff 55 00 90 00 92 00 ad 00 c6 00 b7 00 8d 00 98 00 87 00 8a 00 98 00 8f 00 ca 01 78 03 54 05 bf']
```

to

```
lst2=[ff55, 0090, 0092, 00ad, 00c6, 00b7, 008d, 0098, 0087, 008a, 0098, 008f, 00ca, 0178, 0354,05bf]
```

I tried but it was not as expected:

```
   for i in lst:
        lstNew = []
        tempList =  i.split()
        lenList = len(tempList)
        #print tempList
        index = 0
        while (index < lenList):
            print tempList[index] + tempList[index+1]
            index = index + 2
```

Answer (score 31):

Is this ok:

```
>>> lst = ['ff', '55', '00', '90', '00', '92', '00', 'ad', 
           '00', 'c6', '00', 'b7', '00', '8d', '00', '98', 
           '00', '87', '00', '8a', '00', '98', '00', '8f', 
           '00', 'ca', '01', '78', '03', '54', '05', 'bf']

>>> [ ''.join(x) for x in zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2]) ]
    ['ff55', '0090', '0092', '00ad', '00c6', '00b7', '008d', 
     '0098', '0087', '008a', '0098', '008f', '00ca', '0178', 
     '0354', '05bf']
>>>
```

Or

```
>>> [ x+y for x,y in zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2]) ]
['ff55', '0090', '0092', '00ad', '00c6', '00b7', 
 '008d', '0098', '0087', '008a', '0098', '008f', 
 '00ca', '0178', '0354', '05bf']  
>>>
```

Comment: or `[a + b for a,b in zip(...)]` if you like that better :-)

Comment: ya :) thats looks more neat

Comment: You're missing the closing `]` for `lst`

Comment: This creates two copies of ``lst``

Answer (score 5):

You need to define your list properly. Your list has a single item, a string. This is a list of strings of length 2: (which I think is what you want)

```
lst1 = ['ff', '55', '00', '90', '00', '92', '00', 'ad', '00', 'c6', '00', 'b7', '00', '8d', '00', '98', '00', '87', '00', '8a', '00', '98', '00', '8f', '00', 'ca', '01', '78', '03', '54', '05', 'bf']
```

Then you can do this to create `lst2`:

```
lst2 = []
for i in range(0, len(lst1), 2):
    lst2.append(lst1[i] + lst1[i+1])
```

This is iterating over `lst1` and putting every 2 elements together, then appending it to `lst2`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you had a string  of 2-letter characters separated by spaces you could do:

```
>>> from funcy import ichunks
>>> s = "ff 55 00 90 00 92 00 ad 00 c6 00 b7 00 8d 00 98 00 87 00 8a 00 98 00 8f 00 ca 01 78 03 54 05 bf"
>>> ["".join(chunk) for chunk in ichunks(2, s.split())]
['ff55', '0090', '0092', '00ad', '00c6', '00b7', '008d', '0098', '0087', '008a', '0098', '008f', '00ca', '0178', '0354', '05bf']
>>>
```

This makes use of my favourite library [funcy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcy)

**Update:**

As suggested in the comments; here is a slightly better version:

```
>>> from funcy import ichunks
>>> s = "ff 55 00 90 00 92 00 ad 00 c6 00 b7 00 8d 00 98 00 87 00 8a 00 98 00 8f 00 ca 01 78 03 54 05 bf"
>>> [c[:2] + c[3:5] for c in ichunks(6, s)]
['ff55', '0090', '0092', '00ad', '00c6', '00b7', '008d', '0098', '0087', '008a', '0098', '008f', '00ca', '0178', '0354', '05bf']
>>>
```

Comment: `map(''.join, ichunks(2, s.split()))`

Comment: Or without splitting `[c[1:3] + c[4:6] for c in ichunks(6, lst1)]`

Comment: @ James Mills how to join only FF and 55 together "FF55" when FF and 55 found together in a long list

Answer (score 3):

Given Your list in the Format

```
lst1=[' ff 55 00 90 00 92 00 ad 00 c6 00 b7 00 8d 00 98 00 87 00 8a 00 98 00 8f 00 ca 01 78 03 54 05 bf']
```

let us replace all the spaces and convert it into string

```
list1=''.join([i.replace(" ","") for i in lst1])
```

now we can increment each 4 character to get Result

```
list1= [list1[i:i+4]for i in range(0,len(list1),4)]
print list

#output=['ff55', '0090', '0092', '00ad', '00c6', '00b7', '008d', '0098', '0087', '008a', '0098', '008f', '00ca', '0178', '0354', '05bf']
```